# Unintended spaces in Knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, spaces

With Knockout, I had a foreach to display a list of colors in a scale.

However now trying to resovle a spacing issue, found it was sort of Knockout being the problem.

Basic  setting background color to each item in array.
And since I so love have nicly indented source code, html looks like this:

```
<div class="color-scale" data-bind="foreach: colors">
    <div class="color-scale-item horizontal" data-bind="style: {backgroundColor: $data}"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqvb2fou/)

There is CSS to style Inline-block, which is NOT putting in any space.

Scale looks nice, but add 90+ colors, that space not always needed. So how to remove?

The space is simply due to return line and spacing in the computed html for each div.

I have tried chaning to spans, same result.

so is there a way to write knockout with 'nicely' written source, but does not produce unneeded spaces, without writing on a single line?

```
<div class="color-scale" data-bind="foreach: colors"><div class="color-scale-item horizontal" data-bind="style: {backgroundColor: $data}"></div></div>
```

[JSFiddle single line](http://jsfiddle.net/uqvb2fou/2/)

Comment: `display: inline-block` is exactly the problem. The whitespace in your code is _rendered_ between your inline blocks. This is a common issue when using `inline-block` and there are several methods for overcoming it. See answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Knockout JS. Your issue is with `display: inline-block`. This should get you going:

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

In your case you could probably use a table layout:

```
.color-scale {
    display: table;
}

.color-scale span { /* These spans still left 1px spaces. */
    display:none;
}

.color-scale-item {
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uqvb2fou/3/

UPDATE:

Considering your use case here you might get away with just:

```
.color-scale {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`repeat`](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding will work since it repeats a single element without inserting spaces between them:

```
<div class="color-scale">
    <div class="color-scale-item horizontal" data-bind="repeat: colors" data-repeat-bind="style: {backgroundColor: $item()}"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/uqvb2fou/4/

Comment: also good answer, but went with the css styling. I know in my original question, was leaning toward a knockout solution, also this requires adding the repeat extension, which you should really have stated in your response, and not expect someone to notice the external refence